# How can I add access control 'group' to my Odoo MuK profile as an admin?

Tags: odoo

I have installed MuK Documents,MuK Documents File and MuK Document Access Control inside Odoo.

I have created a root folder with the admin and folders inside it, also I have added a new user.

I would like to add a couple users and let them read and manage some folders inside the root folder but don't allow them to manage all the folders.

Could you please give me some instructions? I have been trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

The access module is currently in its beta and so far I had no time to
write the documentation. But if you want to set access rights to some folders, you have to create an access group first. Therefore just go to the "Access Control" menu and create one  If you want to use the Odoo users just add them under Additional Users. Now go to the folder you want to set the access rights
and add the group to the directory.

Note: If you have a folder structure the lower files and folders will
inherit the groups as well. In case you don't want this behavior just
toggle the checkbox inside the directory.